# Having issues with positioning various elements in CSS

Tags: html, css

I am creating a game where 3 players battle each other, they each have avatars and are faced against each other.

Ok now on to the problem. Once the characters are targeted by skills that last more than 1 turn, an image of that skill is placed to the top left of there character icon ( The enemy team however has the images floated to the right like this prntscr*com/6d354s).

Now here's my issue, when you hover over these effect images they give you a pop up container that shows the effect description (which i've shown in the image linked above)... as you've seen I have managed to get it to work, but it is misplaced im supposed to place the effect description next to the effect icon which isnt working out for the right side.

For the left side, I managed to get it to work prntscr*com/6d34a2 and http://prntscr.com/6d33zy using css hover properties.

```
<div>
  <a class="tooltip">
  <img class="effect-icon">
  <div class="effect-description">
       <h1></h1>
       <p></p>
   </div>
   </a>
</div>
```

In the code above I apply position relative on the container of the effects and I keep the effect description hidden with `display: none;` and I float both left. Then in the css file I set `.tooltip:hover div{display: inline-block; position:absolute;}` which shows the effects description and positions it absolutely next to the image icon without pushing the rest of the images like this prntscr.com*6d3ihu

this method is working but on the right side like I showed before it isn't working, it pushes the div away from he effect icon...

Help me please? :(

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/jEpgbX I have provided an example, I want the right side effect description to show to the left of the icon..

Comment: I can't post more than 2 links, i'm new here, hello to all :O

Comment: Suggestion: You may want to set up an example on jsfiddle.net or http://codepen.io/pen/ - it makes it much easier for someone (like me!) to jump in and play around with your code to help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Difficult to say without seeing an actual demonstration of the problem, but I would suggest modifying the `left` and `right` properties of `.effect-description`.

e.g.

```
.tooltip {display: inline-block;}
.tooltip:hover div{ display: inline-block; position: absolute; top: 0 }
.l .tooltip:hover div {left: 50px;}
.r .tooltip:hover div {right: 50px;}
```

EDIT: After looking at your CodePen demo I have updated my answer and created a fork your pen to demonstrate my answer http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPwKbE

Comment: Edited after looking at the demo. You should give your .tooltip a display value of either block or inline-block.

Comment: Thank you for the silly solution haha I honestly wouldn't come up with that. ( Which is why css isnt my best coding language... )